# unmarshal failed: Near line 0 (last key parsed ''): bare keys cannot contain ':' in Rmarkdown blogdown with Hugo

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, toml

Getting this build error when running `build_site()` in Rmarkdown, I originally ignored the error because it seemed to be fine otherwise. But now after trying to deploy from netlify the error is not allowing for the site to be built and deployed.

I get the error

`unmarshal failed: Near line 0 (last key parsed ''): bare keys cannot contain ':'`

It says the error is in my `config.toml:1:1` file, but the file shows  as `config.toml`, but I didn't manually alter this file, unless blogdown over wrote it? I haven't had this error in many blogs.

my config.toml file is below

```
name: "blog"
title: "blog name"
description: |
  blog name
output_dir: "_site"
navbar:
  right:
    - text: "Home"
      href: index.html
output: distill::distill_article
```

any help would be appreciated, I can show more detail if needed. thank you,

Comment: That appears to be a YAML file, not a TOML file. Did you actually name this file "config.toml", or is this a mistake in the question?

Comment: You are right, I had the wrong file, I have updated it now and continuing my troubleshooting, thank you

Comment: I get "Cannot find the configuration file config.toml | config.yaml of the website", but both files are in the parent directory. I can knit the entire site and it renders fine, but when I run `serve_site()` and `build_site()` I get these errors

Comment: actually, after reading the documentation, .toml files use `key = value` pairs syntax, my colons `:` are wrong, but I don't know how that got like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest version of Hugo, it automatically searches the data in the root directory by default config.toml File, the theme you use must be config.yaml Configuration file for. Just put the original config.toml Just delete it. Note: in. Toml, the ':' self character is not allowed. It should be '='.

Comment: `.yaml` was confusing me as both files were in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that  since this is a distill blog, the .toml/.yaml files are not used, the functions I was using are for blogdown sites, since this is a DISTILL blog, I need to use the functino `render_site()` from the *rmarkdown* package, this renders the .Rmd files into HTML and pushes them to the _sites directory for publishing.